# How to maintain ctime, mtime and atime of file when copying file on NFS v3 drive

Tags: c++, linux, nfs, nfsclient

I am customizing NFS v3 server. When I copy files from other location to NFS Drive on Linux, the copied file times are set to current time.
I think, when copy is done, at least, create, modify are same as source file, but it does not work. I am using NFS v3 protocol.

For example:
cp ./i686-linux-gnu-ar /mnt/nfs

/mnt/nfs : mount point

[image]

As you can see above screenshot, source file and copied file's time attribute are different.

[image]

In NFS server, I know SETATTR is used to set file attribute including time properties, but when I debug it, I couldn't get timestamp "Feb 20  2021" from SETATTR argument.
Actually, The copied file time can be updated only if can get the timestamp ("Feb 20  2021"), I think.

Does anyone know about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `--archive` aka `-a` option to the [cp command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)?

> -a, --archive
> same as -dR --preserve=all
>
> --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
> preserve the specified attributes (default:               mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional               attributes: context, links, xattr, all

Comment: it seems like it is not code issue or nfs protocol leak as you mentioned. If I know more about linux command, i would not post this question.
Let me check again and get back to you. Thanks!